# select2 modal opens on mouse cursor and immediately selects item on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I'm using `select2.full.min.js` in my Ruby on Rails project in order to give one of my `select` tags search functionality. I'm initializing it in the most vanilla way possible: `$( 'select.select2' ).select2();`.

The select2-ified tag seems to work fine, except for one issue - the "modal" when the select is clicked opens over the select element under my mouse cursor as soon as the select is clicked. The problem is, an object is immediately selected and on mouse release, committed to the select tag.

I've seen plenty of examples where the modal always pops up below the select tag, and I'm trying to achieve this functionality, but I'm not really sure what I need to do in order to make that happen. I'm following the examples at the Select2 web site, but don't really see what's wrong here.

Can anyone tell me how I might achieve this? Thank you!

[EDIT] After some investigation, it looks like the problem happens when the viewport is beyond a certain vertical size. If I shrink the browser window enough, the select2 modal pops up above the element. Expanding the viewport size again does not cause the problem to resurface until I refresh the page.

[EDIT2] This appears to have something to do with the calculation select2 uses to decide how to position the modal. It's placed with the following style:

```
position: absolute;
top: 350px;
left: 472px;
```

Dragging the bottom of the viewport up to the bottom of the modal moves it up above the select2 element, and the top value changes accordingly. I can override this with my own CSS to fix it.

Comment: I just noticed that this behavior continues until I open the developer console in Chrome. After that, every time I click the select2 element, the modal appears above it, and persists until I reload the page. If the page is reloaded with the developer panel open, the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: Hmm...the problem only seems to go away if the developer console is attached to the bottom of the Chrome window. If I attach it to the side, or open it in its own window, the problem gets reproduced.

Comment: And on a larger monitor, the problem persists even with the developer console open. If I drag it upwards to shrink the available viewport space, the problem goes away. This definitely seems to have something to do with the vertical size of the browser viewport.

Comment: When you say 'modal' do you mean the Select2 options container? Would you be able to provide the code that you're having trouble with, or at least a pared-down version?

Comment: Hey @Dan Abrey, yep, that's what I mean. The dialog that pops up when you click on the select2 element. I'm afraid the only code worth viewing is what you see above, where I initialize the select2 element. I'm not doing anything special.